# a problem in transferring the float variable with the value of 0.0f to the shader through glUniform1fv (...) or glUniform1f(...)

Tags: opengl, floating-point, glsl, shader, highlight

if I don’t set material.Ns to **0.0f**(I set its value to a positive number other than 0.0f) before I use `shader.setUniform1fv("material.Ns", 1, &(material.Ns));` (**material.Ns is a float variable which is used to set the shininess in the shader**), it will work and I get the correct highlight results, but when I set material.Ns to 0.0f, and then use shader.setUniform1fv(...) to transfer the value of material.Ns to material.Ns in the shader, I can’t get the correct highlight results.

In addition, if I **hard code the value of shinniness in the shader**, such as the following code

```cpp
float shininess = 0.0f;
```

**The results obtained are also correct.**

**Shader::setUniform1fv(...):**

```cpp
void Shader::setUniform1fv(const string &name, int count, float *value) {
    int addr = glGetUniformLocation(sprogram, name.c_str()); // sprogram is the shader id
    glUniform1fv(addr, count, value);
}
```

This is my fragment shader code:

```cpp
#version 330 core

struct Material {
    vec3 Ka;
    vec3 Kd;
    vec3 Ks;
    vec3 Ke;
    vec3 Kt;
    float Ns;
    float Ni;
    float d;
    int illum;
    
    sampler2D map_Ka;
    sampler2D map_Kd;
    sampler2D map_Ks;
    sampler2D map_Ke;
    sampler2D map_Ns;
    sampler2D map_d;
    sampler2D map_bump;
};

struct DirLight{
    vec3 direction;
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
};

uniform Material material;
uniform vec3 viewPos;
uniform DirLight dirLight;

in vec2 TexCoords;
in vec3 Normal;
in vec3 FragPos;

out vec4 FragColor;

void main(){
    /* Texture*/
    vec3 texKa = vec3(texture(material.map_Ka, TexCoords));
    vec3 texKd = vec3(texture(material.map_Kd, TexCoords));
    vec3 texKs = vec3(texture(material.map_Ks, TexCoords));
    vec3 texKe = vec3(texture(material.map_Ke, TexCoords));
    
    /* Final */
    vec3 Ka = material.Ka * texKa;
    vec3 Kd = material.Kd * texKd;
    vec3 Ks = material.Ks * texKs;
    vec3 Ke = material.Ke * texKe;
    
    /* Directions */
    vec3 viewDir = normalize(viewPos - FragPos);
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(-dirLight.direction);
    vec3 reflectDir = normalize(reflect(-lightDir, Normal));
    vec3 halfwayDir = normalize(lightDir + viewDir);
    
    /* Shininese */
    float shininess = material.Ns; // Here's the problem
    
    /* DirLight lighting using Blinn-Phong*/
    float diff = max(dot(Normal, lightDir), 0.0);
    float spec = pow(max(dot(Normal, halfwayDir), 0.0), shininess);
    vec3 ambient = dirLight.ambient * Ka;
    vec3 diffuse = dirLight.diffuse * diff * Kd;
    vec3 specular = dirLight.specular * spec * Ks;
    
    vec3 result = ambient + diffuse + specular;
        
    FragColor = vec4(result, 1.0f);
}
```

**For example:**
In c++ file, I use the following code to set material.Ns in the shader to 0.0f.

```cpp
material.Ns = 0.0f;
shader.setUniform1fv("material.Ns", 1, &(material.Ns));
```

The result i got:
[image: Snapshot 1]

But when I hardcode `shininess` in the fragment shader like this

```cpp
/* Shininese */
float shininess = 0.0f;
[...]
float spec = pow(max(dot(Normal, halfwayDir), 0.0), shininess);
```

The result i got:

[image: Snapshot 2]

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why `glUniform1fv()` for a single `float`? Why not `glUniform1f()`?

Comment: @Scheff I first used `glUniform1f(...)` but the same problem occurred.

Comment: Maybe, something is broken in `shader.setUniform1fv()`. You didn't expose what it is. (In my first comment, I overlooked this - hence, I mentioned `glUniform`. Meanwhile, I found out that there shouldn't be any difference - like observed by you as well.)

Comment: @Scheff The code for setUniform1fv(...) has been added

Comment: The code shown doesn't appear to perform any error checking.  Have you checked the value of `addr` returned by `glGetUniformLocation(sprogram, "material.Ns")`?  Is it valid?

Comment: @G.M. Yes, I checked it before and it is valid(addr != -1). The problem I encountered is that as long as I set `material.Ns` to 0.0f, the result obtained is wrong, but when I set `material.Ns` to other non-zero positive numbers (not 0.0f), the result is right

Comment: Hypothesis: your code is doing pow(0.0, 0.0). When the second 0.0 is a constant, the shader compiler optimizes the whole thing to 1.0. But when you do pow(0.0, 0.0) at runtime, it returns NaN.

Comment: @user253751 This sounds reasonable. [GLSL: pow()](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/pow.xhtml): _The result is undefined if x<0 or if x=0 and y≤0._

Comment: @G.M. Thanks for your help